# Adding custom headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, header

I need to create and add custom headers to an ASP.NET 2.0 application.
The case is simulation of an SSO-login in our dev/test environment.

When I try to add headers I run into the "Not supported on this platform." 
error. BigJim has a nice post on the subject here: 
http://bigjimindc.blogspot.com/2007/07/ms-kb928365-aspnet-requestheadersadd.html

The root of my problem lies in the fact that I need to simulate various 
persons logging into my application. Not just adding static data in a 
HttpModule. I need to take values from a couple of TextBoxes and transfer 
information from these into custom headers and then re-direct the user. The 
HttpModule stuff happens to early in the pipeline...

Does anyone now if there exsist a simple redirect/proxy solution that one 
could use in a dev environment? Or have simple/beautiful way of doing it in code?

Answer (score 1):

One method i have used before, though a long winded approach, is [NUnitASP](http://nunitasp.sourceforge.net/).

This is based on the NUnit framework but intended for ASP.NET UI Testing.

It basically starts a browser in memory, and is able to manipulate the content exactly like a user would.
Using this you could view your page, enter data into textboxes and submit pages.

Hopefully that can help you do the testing you require. I've used it to test load, and spider through sites of mine to gather data.

Answer (score 1):

If you use IIS 7 you can set the Pipeline Mode to **integrated**

This Setting is found in the App-Pool Properties.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but doesn't the `Response.AddHeader()` method still work?

Although, I agree with [Oscar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114772/adding-custom-headers#114913) that a formal testing solution like [NUnitASP](http://nunitasp.sourceforge.net/) is a good idea. Although, NUnitASP is a little dated. I still use it for some of my projects just because it still does work; it just isn't as refined or as simple as [WaTiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) or similar projects.

Answer (score 0):

The browser drops the header if you do a Response.AddHeader()...
The header must be added to the orginal Request...

Answer (score 0):

why don't use ASP.NET forms authentication model?

you define your "private folders". if you attempt to acces to a private folder without login, you automatically are redirected to a your custom login page.

here's a couple of link:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240

http://www.asp.net/learn/security/tutorial-02-cs.aspx